# Another round with overflow:auto in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My image has too big width.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td style="max-width: 800px; overflow-x: auto; position: relative">
                <img style="position: relative" width="1086" height="756" src="my_picture.jpg" id="cropbox" alt="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: "My image has too big width." Nice..

Comment: Picture has scrolls, but as bottom and right borders of all showed picture. Width of `<td>` isn't respected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to clip the image, change overflow-x to hidden

if you want the image to fit the cell change the image width to 100%